# Mi codigo esta muy pegado a su contenedor, debo hacerle un espaciado vertical entre la pared del contenedor y mi lorem

Tags: css, css3, css-grid-layout

Este es mi codigo de CSS, esta muy pegado al contenedor que cubre todo ese bloque, necesito saber como es posible hacer para que le de mas espacio, especialmente a la primera columna de lorem, ayuda porfavor.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
        .servicios{
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
                column-gap: 2rem;
        }
}
.servicio{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;

}
.servicio h3{
        color: var(--secundario);
        font-weight: normal;
}
.servicio p{
        line-height: 2;
}
.servicio .iconos{
        height: 15rem;
        width: 15rem;
        background-color: var(--primario);
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si le das un `padding: 10px` al parrafo, ¿No se arregla?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que la clase servicio es la que se aplica a cada columna (titular, icono, párrafo).
Si le das un padding a .servicio el contenido se debe separar del borde.
Para estar seguro faltaría más detalles sobre el HTML

Comment: No se separa ya lo intente :c

Comment: Aquí como edición podría quedar la otra *respuesta* que aportaste

Comment: Para la próxima edito la mista respuesta, lo he hecho por diferenciarlas pero realmente no es necesario. Gracias por el aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Te amplío la solución que veo con un código HTML que reproduce un poco tu ejemplo
En esta muestra si modificas el padding en la regla **.servicio p** o añades un padding en la regla **.servicio** verás que el borde queda alejado del contenido.
He añadido un par de clases (contenedor, contenedor h2) para crea la página lo más parecida que he podido a tu ejemplo

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>altKey example</title>
<style>
@media (min-width: 768px) {
        .servicios{
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
                column-gap: 2rem;
        }
}
.servicio{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;

}
.servicio h3{
        color: var(--secundario);
        font-weight: normal;
}
.servicio p{
        line-height: 2;
        padding:0 28px;
}
.servicio .iconos{
        height: 15rem;
        width: 15rem;
        background-color: var(--primario);
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
}
.contenedor{width:80%; margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid gray}
.contenedor h2 {width: fit-content; margin:0 auto;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="contenedor">
<h2>Servicios</h2>
<div class="servicios">
<div class="servicio">
    <h3>titulo</h3>
    <div class="iconos">
    <img src="https://loremicon.com/rect/128/128/234397407473/jpg" width="180" height="180" alt=""/> 
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
<div class="servicio">
    <h3>titulo</h3>
    <div class="iconos">
    <img src="https://loremicon.com/rect/128/128/234397407473/jpg" width="180" height="180" alt=""/> 
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
<div class="servicio">
    <h3>titulo</h3>
    <div class="iconos">
    <img src="https://loremicon.com/rect/128/128/234397407473/jpg" width="180" height="180" alt=""/> 
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En lugar de agregar una nueva respuesta, podés simplemente editar la anterior.